# NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' was not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I use .NET Core 5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6 , Blazor webassembly, Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview Version 16.7.0 Preview 6.0

[image]

file `foo.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>browser-wasm</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <UseBlazorWebAssembly>true</UseBlazorWebAssembly>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Blazor" Version="20.1.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.0-preview.7.20365.19" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.0-preview.7.20365.19" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="5.0.0-preview.7.20365.19" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0-preview.7.20364.11" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run debug:

Error

> NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' was not
> recognized

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you run dotnet --version from the command line and let us know what is that version?

Comment: `5.0.100-preview.7.20366.6`

Comment: I suspect DevExpress.Blazor compatibility with .net 5.0. I don't have access to it to check

Answer (score 17):

For .NET Core 3.1 apps, adding `<GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>false</GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>` to the `.csproj` file will prevent this error:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>false</GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This also solves the issue also on 'NUnit Test Project' in a Xamarin.Forms Solution

Comment: Seemed to solve it in .NET 5 as well. Not sure why this error is occuring though. Think any future onlookers would love to get any background into WHY this error is occurring, too (incase you know anything about it)

Answer (score 4):

I just resolved the same issue with this process:

-Close the project

-Delete the bin and obj folders in the Blazor.Client project

-Reopen the project

-Open Nuget Console: Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Nuget Package Manager Console

-Enter **dotnet restore** in the command line

After that I hit F5 and the project compiled, and started

Comment: Thanks for the tip, got me on the right track. I found Visual Studio "Build" > "Clean" then "Rebuild" was enough.